# Bugzilla Migration

Tags: linux, migration, bugzilla

We have Bugzilla 2.20.1 installed(pretty old) which is running on production server. We are 
planning to have migration to the new version. The following are the version which we have installed on server.

OS : Debian Sarge 3.0
Mysql : mysql-server-4.0
PHP : php4
Apache : apache2
Bugzilla : 2.16 (Installed using apt-get)

Please share the document if you have any.

Thanks in Advance... :-)

Comment: Perhaps you should try reading the [official bugzilla documentation](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.0/html/upgrade.html).

Comment: Best of luck. I'm starting work on a similar project right down to the same version of Bugzilla, but it's back-burner and not going to be done soon enough to help you much.

Comment: I didn't understand why the question was down with 2 votes, Did I asked anything wrong which I should ask at server fault?

Answer (score 1):

What the above commenters have not noticed is that you appear to be using Debian Bugzilla, which the Bugzilla team doesn't support because Debian pulls it in all directions to make it fit their system, and in the past that broke some things. So the official documentation probably won't help you sufficiently.

Given that, I would suggest you do the following:

- Dump the database
- Restore it to a new server
- Install Bugzilla 4.0 (latest stable) according to the instructions on the Bugzilla site
- Run checksetup.pl and follow any instructions

and see what happens. You may end up with joy :-)